# Is there an alternative way for collect() in pyspark? py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 0323.collectToPython

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, collect

Pyspark script crashes when i use collect() or show() in pyspark. My dataframe has only 570 rows, so i don't uderstand what is happening.

I have a Dataframe and i have created a functions that extracts a list with distinct rows from it. It was working fine, then suddenly i had an error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
0323.collectToPython
```

A similar error i have when i try to show() the dataframe.

Is there an alternative method to extract a list with distinct values from a dataframe?

```
required_list = [(col1,col2), (col1,col2)]
```

Sorry for not posting the code, but its a large script and its confidential.

Update:

I have a function that extract distinct values from a df:

```
def extract_dist(df, select_cols):
  val = len(select_cols)
  list_val = [row[0:val] for row in df.select(*select_cols)).distinct.na.drop().collect()]
return list_val
```

The function worked fine until i had the error.

I have a main script where i import these function and also another function that calculates a dataframe:

```
def calculate_df(df_join, v_srs, v_db, v_tbl, sql_context):
  cmd = "impala-shel....'create table db.tbl as select * from v_db.v_tbl'"
  os.system(cmd)

  select_stm = "select * from db.tbl"
  df = sql_context(select_stm)

  cmd = "impala-shel....'drop table if exists db.tbl'"
  os.system(cmd)

  join cond = [...]
  joined_df = df.join(df_join, join_cond, 'left').select(..)

  df1 = joined_df.filer(...)
  df2 = joined_df.filer(...)

  final_df = df1.union(df2)

  final_df.show() # error from show

  return final_df
```

Main script:

```
import extract_dist
import calculate_df


df_join = ...extract from a hive table

for conn in details:
  v_db = conn['database'].upper()
  v_tbl = conn['table'].upper()
  v_name = conn['descr'].upper()

  if v_name in lst:
    df = calculate_df(df_join, v_name, v_db, v_tbl, sqlContext)

  df = df.filter(...column isin list)
  df = df.filter(..).filter(..)

  # extract list with distinct rows from df using dist function

  df.show() # error from show

  dist_list = extract_dist(df, [col1,col2]) # error from collect

  for x, y in dist_list:
    ....
```

If i don't use show() the the error appears when i run the collect() method.
The same scripts worked before and suddenly failed. It there a memory issue? i have to clear memory?

SOLVED:

I have found the issue. After i created the dataframe from a table i have dropped the table.

```
  cmd = "impala-shel....'drop table if exists db.tbl'"
  os.system(cmd)
```

After i removed the command with drop table the script ran successfully.
I will drop the temporary table at the end of the script, after i finish with the extracted dataframe. I didn't know that if we create a dataframe and after that drop the source table i will have error afterwards.

Comment: try to give us the key examples of your code in an anoynized way, then we can help

Comment: the problem probably comes from the `transformations` you are doing before the show. Are you using any UDFs ?

Comment: @Steven, i don't have UDFs

Comment: @PV8, i've updated